# i want to unpivot data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here i put SQL code so you can create same data in your instance :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl]
(
[CGSTPer] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[CGSTAmt] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[SGSTPer] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[SGSTAmt] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[IGSTPer] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[IGSTAmt] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
[Id] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl
(CGSTPer,CGSTAmt,SGSTPer,SGSTAmt,IGSTPer,IGSTAmt,Id)
SELECT '2.50','35.10','2.50','35.10','0','0',77371
```

current data is in below format :

```
select * from dbo.tbl

CGSTPer CGSTAmt SGSTPer SGSTAmt IGSTPer IGSTAmt Id
2.50    35.10   2.50    35.10   0.00    0.00    77371
```

i want output like below :

```
id      percentage amount   type
77371   2.50       35.1     cgst
77371   2.50       35.1     sgst
77371   0          0        igst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=80ce1465707d8fba5d4d6e2c63ebe819)**

```
select A.id,percentage,amount,types from
(
select id,[percentage],row_number() over(order by id) r from [tbl]
        unpivot ([percentage] for N in(CGSTPer,SGSTPer,IGSTPer)) as f1
)A inner join
(
select id,[amount],row_number() over(order by id) r from [tbl]
        unpivot ([amount] for N in(CGSTAmt,SGSTAmt,IGSTAmt)) as f2
)B on A.id=B.id and A.r=B.r
inner join
(
SELECT id,types,row_number() over(order by id) r FROM tbl cross apply (VALUES
  ('cgst'),('sgst'),('igst')
) AS y(types)
)C on A.id=C.id and A.r=C.r
```

OUTPUT:

```
id    percentage    amount  types
77371   2.50        35.10   cgst
77371   2.50        35.10   sgst
77371   0.00        0.00    igst
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `APPLY` :

```
select t.id, tt.*
from [dbo].[tbl] t cross apply
     ( values ('CGST', CGSTPer, CGSTAmt), 
              ('SGST', SGSTPer, SGSTAmt),
              ('IGST', IGSTPer, IGSTAmt)   
     ) tt(percentage, amount, types);
```